# CORS headers missing when request header has 'Accept-Encoding' for website of CloudFront + S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser, cors, amazon-cloudfront

we have a s3 bucket that is configured for CORS access. It has a CloudFront instance sitting in front of it. Here is the odd behavior I observed:

URL & Request Header   | CORS headers in response

CF + "Accept-Encoding" | No

S3 + Accept-Encoding   | Yes

CF - 'Accept-Encoding' | Yes

Is it expected? How can I force CF to always return CORS headers in response? 
thank you for any hints/clues

Comment: btw, the value for 'Accept-Encoding' header is 'gzip, deflate, br' as added by browsers

Comment: What about S3 direct, without Accept-Encoding   What does S3 do when that header is absent?  Is CloudFront configured for "compress objects automatically?"  What exact CORS headers are you referring to?  Is CloudFront configured to whitelist `Origin`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, and `Access-Control-Request-Method`?  Did you do a cache invalidation after setting these things up?

Comment: S3 direct without 'Accept-Encoding' has all CORS headers in its response (we configured Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600). I used curl with a GET to get all the above results. It does not matter whether the Origin header is in the request or not, it is the presence of 'Accept-Encoding' that turns off the CORS headers. Actually before i invalidated the cache in CF, it had been working, after I waited 4 ~5 days from when I corrected CORS config in S3. Then I invalidated the cache in CF to find CORS missing

Comment: we didn't config CF to automatically compress objects. But it seems making no difference. I checked it, same thing

Comment: You are saying that a curl request, sent direct to S3, GET, with neither an `Accept-Encoding` nor `Origin` request header actually returns CORS headers in the response.  I cannot duplicate this.  Please provide the exact curl command options.

Comment: I think we were talking about 'Accept-Encoding' header in the request. When no 'Accept-Encoding' header in the request to S3, with Origin header, CORS headers are returned correctly. My question really is, why the presence of 'Accept-Encoding' header makes CF strip those CORS headers in response.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, very strange.

Comment: For anyone else having particular trouble with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` and `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, I have posted a related question at: https://serverfault.com/questions/977818/cloudfront-drops-access-control-expose-headers-header-when-accept-encoding-is-se

Answer (score 1):

I found that this issue appears when you set `access-control-allow-origin: *` in *CloudFront > 'your distribution' > Origins > 'your origin' > Edit > Origin Custom Headers*. To fix this issue I removed that Origin Custom Header, see the screenshot:

---

[image]

---

Also, you need to create an invalidation so changes take effect, *CloudFront > 'your distribution' > Invalidations > Create Invalidation*.
To invalidate all resources you can just pass `/*` in the field or any other valid regexp for your use case